# Image Resize Cover - Keep Top Left of Image

Tags: react-native

[image]I have a big image that needs to be cropped on certain devices, but it's very important that the top left of my image stays in tact because it has some important content.

```
 <View style={{flex:1}}>
     <Image source={MY_IMAGE} 
        resizeMode="cover"
        style={{
          flex: 1.8,
          width: null,
          height: null
        }}
    />
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      //other content
    </View>
 </View>
```

^This is very close to what I want, but by default it looks like resizeMode:"Cover" just zooms in on the center of the image, cutting off my important content.

Is there any way to complete the image resizing based on something like x:0, y: screenHeight so that it keeps the top left of my image and resizes from the bottom right?

Comment: Why not set the dynamic (Fluid) width to the image?

Comment: How so?  When I delete width:null, the image goes WAY off the screen (looks very zoomed in), to a giant size (I guess it's natural width in px)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import necessary packages

```
import { StyleSheet, Image, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
```

Your img element

```
<Image style={styles.images} resizeMode="stretch" source={{ uri: 'src here' }} />
```

Add this styles at the bottom

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    images: {
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
        height: Dimensions.get('window').width / 2
    }
});
```

Try this the image width will be dynamically set even when you rotate your device.

Comment: This zooms in on the center of the image in a very similar way.  I'll try to make an expo snack to show what i mean.

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/rkvO10KAM

Used the best example image I could find on google.  https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf63/img/BorderRadius.png  (top left part should stay in tact)

Comment: use this `resizeMode="contain"` this will fix you issue tried in snack and it worked!

Comment: Thanks for your help by the way Raaj!

I've played around with 'contain' a bit, but that doesn't fit the image to the display, it leaves a blank space behind it, right?  The image needs to cover it's entire container.

I updated the snack so the whole container has a blue background.

https://snack.expo.io/rJhJ8CYCz
The blue background shouldn't be displayed if it's working properly :/

Comment: This is the final try use this `resizeMode="stretch"` worked in the new snack!

Comment: I was able to get it working with a combination of stretch and Dimensions, thanks Raaj!!